# Gdi+ with MSVC++ Compiler getting weird "Native Graphics" runtime error

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

Ok until now I've always coded with GCC so I am new to MSVC++ (and it's errors). I compiled a minimal Win Api program with GDI plus. It compiles fine but closes with a runtime error almost as soon as it starts (I think the runtime error comes when the WM_PAINT message is called). Here's what I see:
[image: What I See]

My code is nothing fancy it just displays a rectangle. ( It works fine when I do it with GDI but doesn't work with GDI+).

My Code:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,FALSE);

ULONG_PTR token;
GdiplusStartupInput inp;
GdiplusStartup(&token,&inp,0);

Graphics g(hdc);
g.Clear(Color(0,0,0));
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color(0,0,0)),10,10,100,100);

GdiplusShutdown(token);
ValidateRect(hwnd,NULL);
```

By debugging I found that the runtime error comes almost as soon as the `Graphics g(hdc);` constructor is called. I can't find anything on google etc. I'm completely lost. Any help?

Comment: Your code is dying with an access violation, segfault in gcc speak.  It isn't clear why from the posted code.  The code is fundamentally wrong, you're supposed to initialize GDI+ at program startup, not in the paint message handler.  And never ignore function return values.  And always call BeginPaint() to get the hdc.  And watch out for debugging 32-bit code on a 64-bit operating system, use Debug + Exceptions to force the debugger to stop on the exception.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You are not correct that GdiplusStartup and GdiplusShutdown can be called only on program startup. Check this link from Microsoft, section Remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Quote: "Call GdiplusStartup and GdiplusShutdown in each of your functions that make GDI+ calls." - this lists Microsoft as one of possible options.

Comment: @truthseeker: Only with the condition that there is a global pair of GdiplusStartup and GdiplusShutdown guarding the entire application lifetime. Otherwise, there is a multithreading race condition bug that can be triggered in one of the GDI+ FontFamily functions. (That function uses non-thread-safe initialization.) GdiplusStartup and GdiplusShutdown works similar to reference-counting: When one is up and running, additional pairs of calls incur low overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinAPI functions always indicate success one way or another. You need to check if `GetDC` returned a valid handle. See the [Return value section of GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx). The access violations in the output also point towards an invalid pointer somewhere. If the DC is valid, check everything else. Make sure you pass pointers where an address is required etc.